# ng-repeat not working angularjs 1.6

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

This is my template for component gamesGrid which I am using in index.html. Inside of this template I have a table on which i want to use ng-repeat but it is not working.

```
<div class="container">           
  <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Platform</th>
        <th>Score</th>
        <th>Genre</th>
        <th>Editor's Choice</th>  
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="detail in gamesDetails">
        <td>{{detail.title}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

This is my component.js file

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
angular.module('myApp').component('gamesGrid', {
    templateUrl: './components/games-grid.view.html',
    controller:'gamesGridController'
});
})();
```

This is my controller.js file

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('gamesGridController',function(gridDataFactory) {

    this.$onInit = function() {


    };

    this.$postLink = function() {
        this.gamesDetails = [];
        gridDataFactory.fetchUserDetails().then(function(response) {
            this.gamesDetails = response;
            console.log(this.gamesDetails);
        });


    }

});
```

And this is my factory:

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('gridDataFactory', function($http) {
    var gameDetails = [];
    var obj = {};

    obj.fetchUserDetails = function(){ 
        return $http.get('http://starlord.hackerearth.com/gamesarena').then(function(response) {
            gameDetails = response.data;
            gameDetails.shift();
            return gameDetails;
        });
    }

    return obj;

  });
```

As you can see i have ng-repeat in my template but it is not working and i am not able to see any data on view.

Comment: In your `gamesGridController`, you are never calling the `this.$postLink` function. Perhaps call it straight after it has been defined so that it executes when the controller is created.

Comment: But i don't need to call $postlink. It will be called once all the elements are linked right

Comment: Also even if I don't use postlink and write the code simply in $oninit it will still not work

Answer (score 2):

You are using **`this.gamesDetails`**  so change your View to use **`controller syntax`** as follows.

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="gamesGridController as ctrl">           
  <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Platform</th>
        <th>Score</th>
        <th>Genre</th>
        <th>Editor's Choice</th>  
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="detail in ctrl.gamesDetails">
        <td>{{detail.title}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
this.$postLink = function() {
 this.gamesDetails = [];
 gridDataFactory.fetchUserDetails().then(function(response) {
  $scope.gamesDetails = response;
  console.log(this.gamesDetails);
 });
}
```

In this piece of code i see you have assigned this.gameDetails, which is not available in the scope. Use $scope.gameDetails to bind it to the view.

Comment: It worked. But can u please explain the reason behind it's failure.

Comment: `this.$postLink = function() {
        this.gamesDetails = [];
        gridDataFactory.fetchUserDetails().then(function(response) {
            this.gamesDetails = response;
            console.log(this.gamesDetails);
        });


    }`

this piece of code actually fetch the data correctly , fail to bind data to the $scope object , which is the object available in the underlying view of the controller.

@NiteshRana see this [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope)